# Unable to find the Documentation in Xcode4

Tags: documentation, xcode4

I was just getting along with XCode4. All of sudden i want to see some documentation. So i rightclicked the text it was not showing "Find Text in Documentation" option :(

I really found this option very useful in learning iOS from XCode 3. versions. All of sudden it is gone. I searched for it and couldnt find it.

So now each time i have to go to Apple Documentation Site and search for it.

Any solutions for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Utility pane and click the Quick Help tab. Selecting text in the source editor shows quick help with hyperlinks to the docs. Alternatively, you can Option-click a symbol to see it in a popup/popover window and can click to open the full documentation from there as well.